# Transferring variables across HTML pages

Tags: html

I am taking in an input from a text box in one HTML page and saving it to local storage using this function.

```
function writeMail(emailInput){
console.log(emailInput);
localStorage.setItem('emailInput',emailInput);
let theEmail = localStorage.getItem('emailInput');
console.log(theEmail);
```

}

This works fine and I can check the inputs are correct through my console logs.
Yet when I try and get this from local storage to store in my table in my emailList html file, it seems to not work at all.

```
<body>
```

email = localstorage["emailInput"];

```
<table>
    <caption> Email list
    </caption>
    <tr>
    <th> Name </th>
    <th> Email </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>email </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: how are you trying to read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you to be able to manipulate the contents of HTML, you need to modify the DOM node specifically. In this specific case you should have an `id` attribute on the `<td>`and then use the `innerHTML` property of that node to set the desired value.

i.e.:

```html
<td id="xpto"></td>
```

then on the code:

```js
let theEmail = localStorage.getItem('emailInput');
document.getElementById("xpto").innerHTML = theEmail;
```

You should also set that code inside of a function that is called once the document has finished loading, so something like:

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
function go(){
   let theEmail = localStorage.getItem('emailInput');
   document.getElementById("xpto").innerHTML = theEmail;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<body onload="go()">
```

Comment: how does the table output the email though. It can recognise the id and pass the variable but what syntax do I use in between the <td> tags to output the email?

Comment: You are mixing concepts. The concept we were discussing above is DHTML (Dynamic HTML), HTML that is manipulated by a browser using a Client Side scripting language, normally JavaScript.
What you might be interested in is a Server Side Scripting language in which case I would recommend you to take a look at PHP (there are many others). Then you have to understand the concepts of HTTP methods such as GET and POST (there are more), and with that you can pass information from page to page, process the information on the next page, and render the output based on the processing that you did.

Comment: I mean Im quite new to javascript and its worked fine for this app so far but I was just saying that the ID tags only defines the location of the space in the table if I'm correct. I need to output the "email" from the javascript in the table, as currently with that code nothing is outputted to the table

Comment: If you are more interested in exploring the client side JavaScript interaction with the UI (User Interface) I would recommend you to take a look at the following technologies: React, Vue, Angular. These are JS frameworks written to make it easier to manipulate the HTML UI. They will usually have a "State" which is the whole information of the current state of your application (i.e. all the information that you want to store and show, normally stored as a JSON object in memory) and have the UI be rendered based on it, and re-rendered automatically when there are changes to it.

Comment: I appreciate your answers but they are essentially Martian Chinese to me. Is there any way to just output this emailInput variable to the table?

Comment: The only way is as i explained above, because that information can only be added, after the loading of the page (and the rendering).
An HTML document is a static file (it doesn't get changed or updated).
What you are doing is storing information on the LocalStorage, which is an area that belongs to your browser. Although this information is associated/related to your document, it does not change or update your document itself. Therefore you can only show it on your document, using JavaScript to retrieve it from the LocalStorage, and then updating the visual place that you determine.

Comment: For better understanding and perspective, would really recommend a simple PHP tutorial :

1. https://www.elated.com/first-php-script/

2. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp