# Outputting from one HTML page to another

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page which takes an input from the user, then saves it using localstorage:

```
function writeMail(emailInput) {
  console.log(emailInput);
  localStorage.setItem('emailInput', emailInput);
  let theEmail = localStorage.getItem('emailInput');
  console.log(theEmail);
  document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = theEmail;
  ...
}
```

I then pass 'theEmail' into another html page and output it to a table. Which I attempt to do below

```
<body onload="go()">
<table>
    <caption> Email list
    </caption>
    <tr>
    <th> Name </th>
    <th> Email </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="email"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

The issue is, from what I've found people are saying its impossible to change the variable in the table to the users Email Input.

I do not need to use a table but is there no way to take an input from a user on one page and output it on another?

The best way to do this for me would be to save it in some king of database or CSV file and print it from that but I am also lost in how to do that.

Comment: Are the pages on the same site? Otherwise, the previous thread you started answered your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521890/transferring-variables-across-html-pages

Comment: No they are not on the same site, if they were would that make it easier? I just create the html files in a folder in intelliaj with my html css and javascript and launch them from there

Comment: Yes, otherwise you need a database for it to happen, and you need a unique ID. You can guess depending on the IP, browser and things like that but the European GDRP will force you to inform the user about this.